# MacBook Pro Shuts down because of a problem

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

This has happened twice in two weeks now. Here's the problem report in the form of one log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       C6100A0F-9E5F-C27D-1439-BD60D7545287

Sat Oct  6 12:21:14 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8012b8776f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8012993333, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff83fb5d5f54, CR3: 0x000000020e4a41b4, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x00000000e843cc0d, RBX: 0xffffff81b03fd400, RCX: 0xffffff81b03fd800, RDX: 0x0202020102010202
RSP: 0xffffff92265abb30, RBP: 0xffffff92265abba0, RSI: 0xffffff81b03fd000, RDI: 0x00000003936320e0
R8:  0xffffff8460aee50c, R9:  0xffffff83fb5d5f54, R10: 0xffffff83edb1510c, R11: 0xffffff81b03fd800
R12: 0xfffffe9b8ba28000, R13: 0xffffff81b03fdffe, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0x0000000000000e2c
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff8012993333, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff83fb5d5f54, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92265ab600 : 0xffffff8012a6c1c6 
0xffffff92265ab650 : 0xffffff8012b95274 
0xffffff92265ab690 : 0xffffff8012b87544 
0xffffff92265ab700 : 0xffffff8012a1e1e0 
0xffffff92265ab720 : 0xffffff8012a6bc3c 
0xffffff92265ab850 : 0xffffff8012a6b9fc 
0xffffff92265ab8b0 : 0xffffff8012b8776f 
0xffffff92265aba20 : 0xffffff8012a1e1e0 
0xffffff92265aba40 : 0xffffff8012993333 
0xffffff92265abba0 : 0xffffff8012adf683 
0xffffff92265abc00 : 0xffffff8012adf29f 
0xffffff92265abc40 : 0xffffff8012ae1151 
0xffffff92265abc70 : 0xffffff8012ae9204 
0xffffff92265abd70 : 0xffffff8012aed8ba 
0xffffff92265abf10 : 0xffffff8012b87ad2 
0xffffff92265abfa0 : 0xffffff8012a1e0f2 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: CEPHtmlEngine He

Mac OS version:
17G65


Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012900000
System model name: MacBookPro11,4 (Mac-06F11FD93F0323C5)


System uptime in nanoseconds: 160913481321788
last loaded kext at 20139723423890: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f958d8000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.8.8
com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse 3.7.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.0
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs 23.0.15
tv.airbeam.driver.AirBeamTV 0.4.0
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.23.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy 3.20.13
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl 3.20.13
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver 4.1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.eficheck 1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 133
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver 133
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 404.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver 439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.70.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs 748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC 1241.31.1a9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext 407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 526
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 680.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 519.20
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler 3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.20.13
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 211.15
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 519.20
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 4.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 133
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver 1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 205
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport 1404.3
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 4.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 288
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM 439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor 1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily 680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm 1


EOF
Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM MBP114.0184.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Intuos5 touch S
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: CEPHTMLEngine refers to a third party HTML library, so this might be some non-Apple software you installed. Usually, that cannot cause a kernel panic, and sometimes it is a red herring since a hardware defect can crash anything and the panic just records what happened to be running at that time. Can you get other crash reports as well? If it’s the same process or a different process each time, we have more to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of 3D party apps.

It is hard to say which one is causing the problem.

While the Adobe `CEPHtmlEngine He` created the Panic, the last loaded Kernel was `com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm` and it is usually that last loaded that makes the problem or conflicts with something.

Adobe recommends to check CPU usage.

Launch Activity Monitor, go to the CPU tab, and check whether `CEPHtmlEngine` Helper process is causing high CPU usage.

and .. Check the log files folder

```
Access ~/Library/Logs/Creative Cloud/Creative Cloud Libraries using the Go to Folder command.
Confirm that the folder exists and you have write permissions for it.
```

As for the last loaded kernel `com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm` it is unclear to me how it get lounched (by whom) and why Adobe has a problem with it.

You do have the `Intuos5 touch S` that is a USB device that might be the one causing the problem.

Following are NON Apple drivers loaded (that are not tested for interfering with OS X) that might need your attention.

```
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.8.8
com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse 3.7.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.0
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs 23.0.15
tv.airbeam.driver.AirBeamTV 0.4.0
```

Comment: You might want to add that the list is also indicating outdated kexts as well. & of those dropbox was a personal pain for me and that airbeamtv thing is obscure to me, as is the dfsfuse-gizmo. –– -> Updates or cruft cleanup is needed anyway.

Comment: thanks for this. don't think the intuos touch caused the panic, the first time it happened, the device was unplugged.